# How to display RecordedVideoTime and Date on top of Video when we are playing that same video

Tags: android

I am implementing android application to capture and play video using Surface-view (or) Video-view classes and saving it on External SD-Card properly. My main problem is i am taking that saved video into windows system which is saved on SD-card, then when i play that video now i need to display the captured date and time on top of that video.

So could you please let me know the possible scenarios or else if any one have some sample code related to this could you please share with me.

Thanks,
Android Team.

Answer (score 0):

> `windows system which is saved on SD-card`

whaat?

> i need to display the captured date and time on top of that video.

if you need to get the time/date of the video, you can use the `lastModified()` method:

```
 File file = new File(pathToVideo);
 Date date = new Date(file.lastModified())
```

To display it when you are playing the video there are several ways, for example you can display it inside the `ActionBar`. For a video playback Activity it is typical to use an overlay `ActionBar`, so use this before calling `setContentView()`:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

You can use `ActionBar.setCustomView(your_action_bar_custom_layout)` to display the date/time or simply use the title/subtitle:

```
getActionBar().setSubtitle(date.toString());
```

Comment: when i played that video in windows PC not on android device then i need to display date and time. How it's possible.

Comment: wait, are you creating your own video player for Windows? Then your question is missing the point

Comment: No. Using android Video recorder i am capturing a video and storing on SD-Card. Now i am pulling this video to windows PC, now i am playing this video on my computer, while playing this video i need to display the date and time on top of video.

Comment: `now i am playing this video on my computer` using which player? And where exactly do you want to show date/time? In some video player? Your question is unclear

Comment: we can play that video using any player like(windows media player, vlc,.....) and which player we are using to play this same video we need to display date and time on that same player.

Comment: so your question is "how to display date/time taken when playing a video using any windows video player"? It's definitely not about programming http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic